# Converting Map to POJO with Jackson, Groovy complains for not having a property

Tags: groovy, jackson

I’m trying to convert a Map from a http response to POJO. The response is

```
{_total=0}
```

In my Pojo, I want to get rid of the underscore so I annotated the field with @JsonProperty. But Groovy complains for not having a _total property

Stacktrace

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{_total=0}' with class 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to class 'io.toro.linkedin.response.CompanyAdminsResponse' due to: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingPropertyExceptionNoStack: No such property: _total for class: io.toro.linkedin.response.CompanyAdminsResponse
Possible solutions: total

    at io.toro.linkedin.connector.LinkedInConnector.linkedInListCompaniesThatUserIsAdminOf(LinkedInConnector.groovy:314)
    at LinkedInTest.list-companies-that-user-is-admin-of(LinkedInTest.groovy:115)
```

Conversion code

```
HttpResponseDecorator response = restClient.get(params)
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.convertValue(response.data as Map, T)
```

POJO

```
package io.toro.linkedin.response

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import groovy.transform.ToString
import io.toro.linkedin.model.Company

/**
 * @author daniel.gomez
 */
@ToString(includeNames = true)
class CompanyAdminsResponse {
    @JsonProperty('_count')
    int count
    @JsonProperty('_start')
    int start
    @JsonProperty('_total')
    int total
    List<Company> values
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you get rid of the toString annotation?

Comment: no, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem comes from your response transformation to `Map`: `response.data as Map` which you're passing to `mapper.convertValue` method.

I make a groovy script using directly the follow `Map` `[_total : 3]` to test your problem, and there is no exception thrown an the object is created correctly:

```
@Grab('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3')
@Grab('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3')
@Grab('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3')
@GrabExclude('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all')

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import groovy.transform.ToString

class Company {
}

@ToString(includeNames = true)
class CompanyAdminsResponse {
    @JsonProperty('_count')
    int count
    @JsonProperty('_start')
    int start
    @JsonProperty('_total')
    int total
    List<Company> values
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
def object = [_total : 3]
println mapper.convertValue(object, CompanyAdminsResponse) 
// the above line prints CompanyAdminsResponse(count:0, start:0, total:3, values:null)
```

Hope this helps,